# Python: Building Dictionary With Multiple Responses (Nested Dictionaries?)

Tags: python, csv, processing

I'm trying to figure out how to most efficiently search for lines ins a ~23 million line CSV file in python.

The file is a list of ZIP+4 codes, and some information about each, mainly their FIPS ID, state abbreviation and county.

For example line 1 is {02468,1405,25,017,25017,MA,MIDDLESEX} those values are {5_Dig_Zip,+4_Dig_Zip,StateFIPS,CountyFIPS,TotalFIPS,State_Abbrev,County}.

I'd like to build a dictionary, or some other data structure to be able to query:

data["02468"] --> and return all of the lines where the 5 digit ZIP is 02468, or data["02468"]["1405"], and return just that line.

The data currently sits in a large list of lists. It seems like I might want to use nested dictionaries, but I'm not quite sure where to head.

Thanks!

Comment: 23 million records?  You'd be much better off storing them in a database and using the database's query functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic: make a `pandas` dataframe with a multi-index (first level: 5 digit zip, second level - 4 digit extension).
Less pythonic, but easy: make an sqlite database and query in the usual way.